# How to duplicate a checked out branch to a new one so I can continue working on current?

Tags: git

I know there are many versions of this question but I could not find a solution to my exact requirement.

If you could point me to one I'll be grateful.

If not, could you please advise?

Suppose I am working now on a long time feature branch named my_feature_branch which serves me for all my developments tasks, but I'd like to put current changes aside for a while and continue to work on my current checked out feature branch.

How can I duplicate the current branch with all its commits to another branch?
 Or would you recommend a better method. like stash maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`git log -<some_number_here>` will give you all the commits of your current branch. "Keeping changes aside" means to `git checkout <commit_hash>` some specific commit from past, where abovementioned changes do not exist; thus you would get into a "detached mode" with no named branch yet. The last step is `git chechout -b new_branch_name` - to enforce named branch within given state. As far as I understood your prolem, that't the "gitish" way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the current branch with all its commits to another branch.

```
git checkout -b another_branch
```

Commit you changes.

```
git add . && git commit -m "Put current changes aside"
```

Continue to work on your current checked out feature branch.

```
git checkout my_feature_branch
```

As simple as that.